# Height overflow in semantic-ui

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

Here's an example.

https://jsfiddle.net/ustjx0po/2/

```
<div class="ui top attached large menu red inverted">
<a  class="header item item_one ">
    <i class="sidebar icon"></i> Menu
</a>
<div class="menu"><a  class="item">Home</a>
    <a  class="item">Form</a>
    <a class="item">Help</a>
</div>
<div class="right menu">
    <a  class="header item ">
        <i class="remove circle icon"></i> Logout
    </a>
</div>
```

My problem is that I have unnecessary overflow (height overflow) . I want to get rid of it.
But I would like for my sidebar to fill rest of the height when it opens.

And I wouldn't want to just add overflow:hidden; because I might have content that actually overflows full height.

Comment: Hi. have you tried asking someone in https://gitter.im/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI ?